# Association references unmapped class hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

The configuration for Affiliate class is:

```
<class name="AffiliatesDO" table="AFFILIATES">
    <id name="affiliateId" column="affiliate_id" type="java.lang.String">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="customerId" column="customer_id" type="int" />
    <property name="affiliateType" column="affiliate_type" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="site" column="site" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="status" column="status" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="createdBy" column="created_by" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="creationDate" column="creation_date" type="java.util.Date" />
    <property name="lastUpdatedBy" column="last_updated_by" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="lastUpdated" column="last_updated" type="java.util.Date" />
      <set name="address" lazy="true" inverse="true" order-by="address_id asc">
        <key column="address_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="AddressDO"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

The Configuration for Address class is

```
<class name="Address"
    table="Address">
    <id name="addressId" column="address_id"
        type="java.lang.String">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>


    <property name="name" column="name" type="java.lang.String" />

    <property name="address1" column="address1" type="java.lang.String" />


    <property name="phone" column="phone" type="java.lang.String" />

    <property name="landLineNumber" column="land_line_number" type="java.lang.String" />

    <property name="faxNumber" column="fax_number" type="java.lang.String" />

</class>
```

I am getting the below error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: com.infibeam.customerservice.dbObjects.AddressDO
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(HbmBinder.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder$CollectionSecondPass.secondPass(HbmBinder.java:2652)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:43)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1054)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:296)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1039)
at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.configuration.AbstractComponentConfiguration.getConfiguration(AbstractComponentConfiguration.java:38)
at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.HibernateExporterMojo.configureExporter(HibernateExporterMojo.java:186)
at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.exporter.Hbm2JavaGeneratorMojo.configureExporter(Hbm2JavaGeneratorMojo.java:69)
```

Kindly show me the mistakes I have made.. I want to use one to many relation AffiliateDO->AddressDO

Comment: can you show show us com.infibeam.customerservice.dbObjects.AddressDO mapping as well?

Comment: i have placed the addressDO mapping..

Comment: are they both in same xml? as perviously you mentioned some customerservice and affliateService?

Comment: no they are in different xml files...Affiliate Service and Customer Service are the two projects ...Affiliate mapping is in AffiliateService and Address mapping is in CustomerService..I am also using struts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your mapping of the parent class is referring to AddressDO, but the subsequent child mapping is referring to Address (No "DO")... If I had to guess, you should change the second mapping to AddressDO (or visa versa).   In any event, looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Do as a typo error in Addrees xml, The Address mapping seems incorrect, there must address_id must be many-to-one currently it is generated new one.